# In Xcode, can you recompile part of an app while it's running but paused at a breakpoint?

Tags: xcode4, recompile

In Xcode, can you recompile part of an app while it's running but paused at a breakpoint?

I thought that there was a way to do this. I thought I remember hearing that Xcode 4 would have this ability, or something like this.

It would also be useful if I could change the value of a variable while the app is paused, to narrow down where a bug is happening.

It seems unlikely that this is possible to do, but I thought at least I'd ask, if for any other reason than just to get my daily serving of humble pie :D

(I am compiling my app for iOS.)

Answer (score 0):

Wow that would be nice! I am going through the Standford course right now and the teacher specifically says that if you change the code or any work that requires compiling you must recompile the whole project.

So assuming he is correct, I doubt that this is a current feature in xCode. Hopefully they will add something like this though!